# Div Overlay over an existing .jpg Image

Tags: php, html, widget, overlay

I would like to do the following:

I have an existing .jpg [picture](http:///www.spuehler-tv.ch/webcam/Webcam_Eglisau_Image.jpg) from a Webcam.

Now I would like to overlay this Picture with the following Widget:

```
<div style="width:250px"><a href="http://wetter.webmart.de/782303" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">Wetter in Eglisau</a><br /><script src="http://wetter.webmart.de/e/782303"></script></div>
```

Then the picture should be saved under a new name in the same folder.

Can I do this with a PHP Script?

I have searched tutorials, but the are all for only text or Image over Image etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, php can't help you with this. If you need to produce just one single picture, then image editor will do.
But I guess, you need to automate this process with fresh webcam images and weather updates. I would recommend to create a web page with two image as @MilanG suggested using css tricks. After that you can use some headless browser to capture the screen, e.g. PhantomJS http://phantomjs.org/ will do.
Again, as I wrote in the beginning, php cannot help you with this task.

Answer (score 0):

You have image manipulation libraries for PHP. i.e.:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

if you want that overlay to be part of the image.

Other way use absolute positioning for overlay block, give it higher Z-index and place it over the image.

Comment: I would like to do it without Extensions. (i don't have a clue how they works^^) The Way with an overlay block is good, but how to save the Picture again with the Overlay?

Comment: Overlay block solution doesn't involve PHP nor image editing, but whole trick is done with HTML and CSS. Simply, one HTML block is positioned absolutely (by specifying it's X, Y, and Z coords) and placed over other HTML block.
But why you don't want to use image libraries? They are kinds standard and available almost everywhere. They are not hard to use neither.